# Should I put the code behind for a button click in my viewModel and if so how can I bind it?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have XAML code looking like this:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" x:Name="nButton" Text="Don't Know" />
```

and a viewModel that I have linked up:

```
public CardViewModel card = new CardViewModel();
phraseGrid.BindingContext = card;
```

The ViewModel looks like this so far:

```
public class CardViewModel : ObservableProperty
{
    string cvmLabel;

    public CardViewModel() { }

    public string CvmLabel
    {
        get { return cvmLabel; }
        set {
            if (value != cvmLabel) {
                cvmLabel = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CvmLabel");
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
```

Currently I have coded this in the back end C#.

```
        nButton.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
        {
            App.DB.IncrementScore(App.cfs, phrase, 1);
            App.correctButtonPressed = 1;
            ResetTimer2();
        };
```

What I would like to know is if this is more appropriate in the viewModel and then if I put it there, how is the best way to code it and link up the binding for the button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's a lot better to implement all the logic in the viewmodel. Handling the clicked event in the code behind couples your view with the code behind and makes unit testing a lot harder. In overall, it's always best to try to reduce coupling as much as possible.

You should use the Command parameter of the button to point to an ICommand in your viewmodel like this:

**XAML**

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" x:Name="nButton" Text="Don't Know" Command="{Binding ButtonClickedCommand}" />
```

**ViewModel**

```
public ICommand ButtonClickedCommand {get; set;}

public CardViewModel() 
{
    var ButtonClickedCommand = new Command (() => Debug.WriteLine ("Command executed"));
}
```